# c# Random Designer Crash while Switching TabControl Tabs

Tags: c#, winforms

I created a forms application and placed a tab control on it. In the same project I added a UserControl with all the controls one tab would need. I then placed this UserControl on the second tab of the tab control.

Now, when I open the designer to modify the forms application it loads OK (although it takes longer than usual) but when I select the second tab MSVS just freezes, says it's encountered an error, and restarts (most times). Once I was given the option to "debug".

I clicked the "debug" button which opened a new MVS 2005 window and displayed: "Unhandled exception at 0x10d84c12 in devenv.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000."

No idea what is going on... :(  Tried restart but didn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does your project involve any unmanaged code or controls?

Comment: @SLaks: I don't think so, but I cannot guarantee this. I am using several controls from a .dll I did not write. That gives me an idea, I will try deleting those controls and see if it resolves the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would probably happen if your control ends up executing unmanaged code.

Make sure that the control's source code doesn't do anything if `DesignMode` is true.

It might also happen if you use ActiveX controls; try removing them in code if the control is in design mode.
You can do that in the `Load` handler:

```
if (DesignMode)
    somePanel.Remove(someControl);
```

Comment: Hmmm, so do you mean that the control was probably created using unmanaged code or that it calls (through a click event, e.g.) unmanaged code and that is the issue? Ohhhh... I do use a "Visible Changed" event, maybe that is causing the issue!

Comment: All of your event handlers shouldn't do anything `if (DesignMode)`

Comment: Well, it's working now. I re-added the controls, and added the `if(DesignMode)` to the VisibleChanged event handler. Interesting, do you recommend adding this test to all event handlers or just specific ones (e.g. VisibleChanged, Load, etc.)? I'm not a CSci major so I'm going for best-practices! :)

Comment: @Jon: Add it to any handler that can run in design mode (eg, not mouse or keyboard events, which the designer will block), that has code that shouldn't run in the designer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with tabcontrol, but it was because a child control runned some code into its _Load event, even if the code was wrapped by if(DesignMode), it was still executed.
The solution was to create a field to save the designmode flag in the constructor, then read it into the load event.